# How to get phpmyadmin credentials of application in openshift

Tags: openshift

I create an application on openshift
But I forgot to note down my mysql and phpmyadmin credential

now I cannot access phpmyadmin

Please point me a way to get through this.

Best Regardes,

Nathan

Comment: This isn't a programming question, and I know nothing about OpenShift, but I'll bet you can either get or reset your credentials from their portal

Comment: thanks but this does not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see all the details of your app (including phpmyadmin credentials) by using `rhc apps` command.

See description/examples [here](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/using-rhc-to-manage-paas-apps).

Comment: Ahhh... silly me, I saw that before. Thank you very much. You my time saver

Answer (score 2):

There are actually two commands you can use:

1) rhc domain show

This will show you all the applications in your domain

2) rhc app show

This will just show the information specific to your application

You can also go to the web console and then manage the application and it will show it there.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL5.5 username and password is your phpmyadmin's username and password

[image: Figure 1]